# Adding values in a column based on a query result

Tags: mysql, alter-table, alter

I have a table:---

| id | name | dept |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | CS |
| 2 | Bob | Elect |
| 3 | David | Mech. |

and a query result:-

| id | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 22 |
| 3 | 50 |

Then I want to add the count column from the query to my original table, something like:-

| id | name | dept | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | CSE | 100 |
| 2 | Bob | Elect | 22 |
| 3 | David | Mech. | 50 |

The only I figured out to do, is by storing the query result into a new table and then using UPDATE...SET...WHERE. Is there any way to do it without creating a new table?

Comment: `and a query result` ... what is the query?

Comment: `UPDATE your_table inner join (your query result) as t1 on t1.id=your_table.id set your_table.count = t1.count ` . First you need to create the count column in your table

Comment: You don't have a column in your table to hold count - unless there is something you are not telling us,

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The query is  SELECT id, count(*) FROM tablename GROUP BY id;

Comment: @P.Salmon yeah, I want to add a new column to hold count. So assuming I add a new column using ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN count INT;

Comment: Unless you second table is static (and it seems from your query that it isn't)  I wouldn't store the count I would calculate it as and when needed using a join or a view,

Comment: @P.Salmon second table is the result of a query `SELECT id, count(*) FROM tablename GROUP BY id;`

Comment: @Ergest Basha I know - what's your point?

Comment: @P.Salmon there is no second table

Comment: *I want to add the count column from the query to my original table ... Is there any way to do it without creating a new table?* Firstly alter your table and add needed column of correct datatype. Then update the table and set values into this new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create the count column in `tablename` using

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD COLUMN `nr_count` INT;
```

Then use:

```
update tablename t
inner join ( SELECT id, 
                    count(*)  as nr_count 
             FROM tablename 
             GROUP BY id
           ) as t1 
set t.nr_count=t1.nr_count ;
```

Comment: what you've written seems to be working fine. What also worked for me was as follows:- 

WITH t1 as ( SELECT.... ) UPDATE t1, t2 SET t1.count = t2.count WHERE t1.id = t2.id;